# Error al entrar a RStudio, r o a la aplicacion

Tags: r

Instale el paquete packrat para manejar las versiones de mis librerias pero al pasarlo al equipo donde tengo las aplicaciones no me funciona y me sale un error donde busca el archivo `packrat/init.R`, todo falla y al entrar a RStudio, R o a la aplicacion, sale el error.

> Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :    no se puede
>   abrir la conexión Además: Warning message: In file(filename, "r",
>   encoding = encoding) :   no fue posible abrir el archivo
>   'packrat/init.R': No existe el archivo o el directorio Error in
>   tools:::httpdPort <= 0L :    comparación  (4) es posible solo para
>   tipos lista y atómico

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Encontré que en el archivo `.Rprofile` de mi usuario tenia:

```
#### -- Packrat Autoloader (version 0.4.6-1) -- ####
source("packrat/init.R")
#### -- End Packrat Autoloader -- ####
```

Lo edite comentando la linea `source("packrat/init.R")`.

Me funciono.